# list.files: regex pattern not working on windows?

Tags: r, regex

I can access and get the path of my file with `file.choose()`:

```
"D:\\amca\\reportes_mov\\data_mym\\mym_total_csv\\hhhh-2020-11-09.csv"
```

I'm using a project, so I don't have to type the whole path, but after `reportes_mov`. Why my list files is empty after I run it?

```
files  <- list.files(pattern = 'data_mym\\/mym_total_csv\\/hhhh-2020-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\.csv')
```

Other attemp: still empty.

```
files  <- list.files(pattern = 'data_mym\\mym_total_csv\\hhhh-2020-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\.csv')
```

Comment: After `data_lsd` and `lsd_total_csv` there seems to be a `/` instead of ``\`` in the pattern

Comment: @Thefourthbird please, look at my other attemp.

Comment: I see, try changing `\\.` to ``\.``

Comment: see update 1, please.

Comment: Then perhaps double escape them `data_lsd\\\\lsd_total_csv\\\\america-2020-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\.csv`

Comment: Could it because pattern only deals with the file's name and not the full string of path + name.
What happens if you do : files  <- list.files(path = "data_lsd\\lsd_total_csv\\", pattern ="america-2020-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\.csv") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern` param of [`list.files`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/list.files) only matches the file name part not the path:

> `path`: a character vector of full path names; the default corresponds
> to the working directory, getwd()...
>
> `pattern`: an optional regular expression. *Only file names* which
> match the regular expression will be returned.

And if I understand correctly, you will also need the param `full.names = TRUE`

> If TRUE, the directory path is prepended to the file names to give a
> relative file path. If FALSE, the file names (rather than paths) are
> returned.

Try

```
files  <- list.files(path = 'data_lsd/lsd_total_csv', pattern = 'america-2020-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\.csv', full.names=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Which outputs the CSVs in the subdirectory as expected:

```
[1] "data_lsd/lsd_total_csv/america-2020-11-09.csv"
[2] "data_lsd/lsd_total_csv/america-2020-11-10.csv"
```

Comment: It does not look like Windows. Your test paths are not at `D:\america\reportes_mov`.

Comment: No need. We are inside a project and when working in Windows, we may either use forward slashes or escape backslashes using a double backslash in paths.